# Zend Form Validation and Filtering without Zend Forms

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-validate, zend-filter

Is there a way to validate and filter pure HTML forms with Zend Validation and Zend Filter classes ? Please give some example if you have, I couldn't find out any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$email           = $this->_getParam('email');// form's $_POST or $_GET
$email_validator = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();

if(!$email_validator->isValid($email)){
    // Error, throw(Exception)
}
```

To see what validation you can use, open your library folder and go to
library/Zend/Validate/  path, you will see many files/classes. That are available classes for validation like Alnum.php, Alpha.php, Barcode.php, CreditCard.php, etc. Just create instance and call method  isValid();

```
new Zend_Validate_FileName();
```

The same thing is for filters, on path library/Zend/Filter/ you can see a lot of classes. Almost all of them implement an interface Zend_Filter_Interface(Interface.php) where you can find one method:

```
public function filter($value);
```

Comment: Is there a way to validate set of form elements rather than one by one?

Comment: Got an example, have to try and see. http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/zend_filter_input-zend_validate-messages/

Comment: On that example you can see eg. $validators = array('body'=>'Alpha'); where key is $_POST['body'] and validation is Alpha.php. Apply that logic to everything else... and call only once if($input->isValid()){...}